# AS400 - A SQLRPGLE module program got abended in a batch submission - On dump I'm getting Statement number. However on compiling I'm getting Line no

Tags: ibm-midrange

One of my job errored out with Msg ID - **MCH1210**, *reciever value too small.* On dump I'm getting Statement number however on Compiling the object I'm getting line no. Even on Interactive debug I'm getting line no, How can I get the statement number for the program.  Object is a SQLRPGLE module also note module is compiled using CRTSQLRPGI followed by CRTPGM.

Comment: statement number is usually pretty close to line number.  In the wild MCH1210 is usually found in a small size variable.  For example a three digit or four digit number.  is > 999 overflowing.  Also You should learn to do a single step compile by specifying a binding directory on a H spec in the program.

Comment: @danny117 - Not sure we are thinking of the same thing, but in my experience, the line numbers in the compile listing are usually quite far from the sequence numbers stored in the source. (Also, "line number", "sequence number", and "statement number" are all inherently ambiguous terms, so it's helpful to say whether you're talking about compile listing or source member.)

Comment: If it says statement  10200 search for 102 in the compile listing or visa versa.

Comment: @danny117 - That hardly ever works for the kinds of programs I work with every day. Externally described files (just as one simple example) get expanded into numbered lines (one per field) in the compile listing, and these have no corresponding lines in the source. I'm looking at a very small, rudimentary program right now whose last D spec is line 20.00 (or 2000) in the source and 20 in the compile listing; but the first C spec is line 21.00 (or 2100) in the source but 72 in the compile listing.

Comment: @JohnY Source sequence numbers are usually only useful for source manipulation. They usually may be ignored for debug. For debug, you should only care about compiled statement numbers. Statement #50 will follow statement #49, but there can be numerous source sequence numbers between them, especially because a single *statement* can span a significant range of sequence numbers.

Comment: @user2338816 - That was my point precisely. You should be directing your comment at danny117, because you are simply backing me up.

Answer (score 1):

add the "source statement" compiler option..

```
h option(*SRCSTMT)
```

free format

```
ctl-opt option(*SRCSTMT);
```

or on the compile command

```
CRTBNRPG <...> OPTION(*SRCSTMT)
```

Comment: I know you meant `ctl-opt` instead of `dcl-h`

Answer (score 0):

If you have H-spec option OPTION(*SRCSTMT), and you compile with CRTSQLRPGI OPTION(*NOSEQSRC) (the default), then the statement number in the error message will correspond to the sequence number in your SQLRPGLE source.

Just be aware that it's possible that there will be multiple statements in your program with the same sequence number. OPTION(*NOSEQSRC) tells the SQL precompiler to put the original sequence numbers into the generated RPGLE source file in QTEMP/QSQLTEMP1. If you have executable statements in copy files, you might have two different statements with the same number.

If RPG OPTION(*NOSRCSTMT) is in effect, the statement number is the number shown on the left of the listing.

If RPG OPTION(*SRCSTMT) is in effect, the statement number is the Line number shown on the left of the listing, **unless** the statement came from a copy file. In that case, there will be a + next to the number on the left. Add 1000000 * SrcId to the Line number. The SrcId is listed on the right-hand side of the listing in the "Src Id" columns 121-124.

```
*...+....1....+....2....+....3....+....4....+....5....+ // ..+....2....+....3..
Line   <---------------------- Source Specifications -  //  Change Src Seq
Number ....1....+....2....+....3....+....4....+....5..  //  Date   Id  Number
002800+C                   eval      zero = 1 / zero        170424    3000100

Line Number = 002800
Src Id = 3 
Statement number = 3 * 1000000 + 002800 = 3002800
```